# How to run a cmd command from user input and then prompt for a second input after?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make my life as a technician easier by writing a program that simplifies a lot of the tasks that I do day to day like running certain command prompts. I have successfully made the code request for user input and run a cmd command from that input but once the command runs in cmd, my program stops and displays the file path for the program. I cannot figure out how to get a second prompt to run another cmd command. Here is what I have so far:

```
import subprocess, traceback, types
import os
print('1. sfc scan')
print('2. dism')
print('3. ol Gabehart')
print('4. user list')
print('5. print functions')


key = int(input('Input your choice: '))
if key == 1:
    os.system('cmd /k "sfc /scannow"')
elif key == 2:
    os.system('cmd /k "dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth"')
elif key == 3:
    os.system('cmd /k "dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth && sfc /scannow"')
elif key == 4:
    os.system('cmd /k "net user"')
elif key == 5:
    os.system('cmd /k "net stop spooler && net start spooler"')



key2 = int(input('Input your choice: '))
if key2 == 1:
    os.system('cmd /k "sfc /scannow"')
elif key2 == 2:
    os.system('cmd /k "dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth"')
elif key2 == 3:
    os.system('cmd /k "dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth && sfc /scannow"')
elif key2 == 4:
    os.system('cmd /k "net user"')
elif key2 == 5:
    os.system('cmd /k "net stop spooler && net start spooler"')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the `/K` switch to the `cmd` command prevents the new command prompt that you are launching from terminating after it finishes running whatever command is being passed to it. So this should work it you use the `/C` switch instead.

But why explicitly run `cmd` at all when the `system` command by definition runs whatever command you specify by first launching the default Windows command processor, which should be `cmd`? In other words, you are running one *extra* level of `cmd`. Try for example:

```py
if key2 == 1:
    os.system('sfc /scannow')
```

Comment: Thanks! this fixed my issue. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the Cmd package? I think it applies to your code as a simple solution.

[Here is an example from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd-example)

```
import cmd

class PastorShell(cmd.Cmd):
    intro = 'Welcome to the pastor shell.   Type help or ? to list commands.\n'
    prompt = '(pastor) '

    def sfc_scan(self, args):
       # your code goes here
       pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PastorShell().cmdloop()
```

you can implement all of your methods there in that class